# Which one is correct, "by the window" or " at the window" and why?

Tags: prepositions

The given sentence is: He said that he left the parcel on the chair (by/at) the window. The correct answer is said to be "at". What's the explanation?

Comment: This is one of many examples in English where there is a choice of prepositions. Sometimes there may be a small (or large) difference in what the preposition signifies. In this case, there is none.

Comment: As a Brit, stylistically, I'd have said 'by'. I couldn't say why, tbh, it just feels better. Maybe 'at' is more US Eng.

Comment: @Tetsujin - 'by' would be this American's choice, too. But I wouldn't bristle at 'at' instead. I think 'at' may sound a bit more stilted, but only slightly. I think Ronald hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @J.R. - oddly, I wouldn't feel in any way uncomfortable if I stood at the window, but for some inexplicable reason, the chair next to me isn't 'at' it, it's 'by' it. Not a hope in heck of me being able to rationalise that to myself, let alone anyone else. *Maybe* .. at has some connotation of 'looking out of it' which the chair can't do... but I'm not going to get any more rational than that ;)

Comment: I don't have a problem with either of them. I would more naturally say **by**, but **at** sounds just fine too.

Comment: Keep in mind that a *window* could also be a counter where an employee assists customers (behind glass or not), such as at a bank or the post office. So maybe "He left his keys *at the window* while he was in the bank."

Comment: Was there a picture associated with the sentence? If I had to distinguish the cases, I would say that a chair *by* the window would be a chair with its back against the wall to the side of a window; a chair *at* the window would be facing the window, so that a person seated in the chair could look through the window. That's a bit stilted, but I think possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> **at** the window
>   **by** the window

would be understood to meaning *in the vicinity* or *nearby* the window.

However, the nuance can be seen in

> He stood **by** the window.
>   *He stood close by the window*

where the person may or may not be seen, whereas

> He stood **at** the window.
>   *He stood in the window.*

means the person could be seen from the *other side* of the window.